# React -native listens to android return key to exit multiple select

Tags: react-native

Listening for other pages in react native can return normally, but there is one page where I want it to exit multiple selection when it presses the return key. What should I do

multi picture is here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ji46.png)
exit multi picture is here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGjo8.png)

when i enter android back key,i want i from 2 to 1.

```
componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackClicked);
  }
   onBackClicked =  () => {
     const {route} = store.dataFixStore;
    if (route != 'Home' && route!='siteEmail') {
          return true;
    }else if (route == 'siteEmail'){
      this.handleMoreSelect()
    } else {
      if (this.lastBackPressed && this.lastBackPressed + 500 >= Date.now()) { 
          return false;       
       }
      ToastAndroid.show("再按一次退出应用", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      this.lastBackPressed = Date.now();
      return true;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Mind to elaborate further on what is exit multiple selection?

Comment: Is a page which has the function of multiple-choice, press the return key to exit the current in the page pops up

Comment: I updated the picture，can you help me?